# Is there a quick way to specify that you do not want "auto tags" in your search?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

Recently, I've noticed a recurring issue when searching. I will try searching a couple of keywords, but when the search results are shown, the keywords are turned into tags. Coincidentally, it happened again as I was trying to find answers before asking. The entered key-phrase, *search scope*, was turned into [search] [scope].

I have been using this search and have never noticed issues until recently. I can't help but think that it will only get worse as the site grows, as the core of the issue seems to be the number of existing tags. Don't get me wrong, I am not complaining about the tag system. I think it is a great feature which was superbly implemented, and which is constantly being maintained and made better by the diligent and hard-working members of our community.

What I meant was, as software development advances, technologies blossom, and new libraries are created, the number of legitimate tags is guaranteed to keep growing.

I also have no problem whatsoever with the auto-tagging feature. In most situations it is helpful. The only time that I have noticed the results being negatively impacted is when an unpopular tag gets auto-tagged. Maybe increasing the chances of auto-tag for more popular tags is a possible solution? (This isn't the main question, just a thought.)

In this light, I was hoping to find (or, if needed, request) a way to toggle the auto-tagging feature on and off. (BTW if someone could comment on the actual name of this feature, I will update the post - I searched for it, but without results.) I spent some time yesterday looking for info on search configuration, but I couldn't find anything on auto-tagging. I then spent about an hour and a half reading through old research, but I couldn't even find the feature's name (which is likely why I didn't find much else.)

**So is it possible to toggle the auto search on and off for those situations where it hinders my results? If it is not, could it be added as a feature?**

Comment: Only the top few tags become keywords so an unpopular tag can never be auto-tagged. A significant number of your assumptions are therefore incorrect. I.e. it can't get worse as the site grows etc.

Comment: maybe I am just getting unlucky

Comment: Tags like search also have many meanings. Ive run into the situation where I will use it one way and the tag is for another meaning. Is there a way to protect against this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags

Comment: In 2014 it was 60. Where is it at now.

Comment: As for the link, I spent about half the day yesterday doing research for this Q. I couldn't find anything on this feature. I commend you. Ironic that a question about the SO tag / search implementation would end up on the SE main meta.

Comment: *In 2014 it was 60. Where is it now?* Try it and see if you think it may be different.

Comment: Is there a proper term for this feature, so I can search for a wiki. I found the search features wiki. I have it on my browser hot bar. There was nothing about it there.

Comment: I'm going to test it as the person in the comment did and get an exact # so  this page will at least be of a bit of value to the site.

Comment: Currently, the top 120 tags get auto converted when used in search. If you put the search terms in quotes, it prevents auto conversion to tags.

Comment: @RobertLongson I was hoping to get the chat prompt. The results of my "testing" has my nerd senses peaked. While I can not fairly dispute the "60" without testing every tag, I definitely *can* dispute the "top" aspect. I do not know if they were hard-coded and maybe the results have changed (although I doubt that someone just keeps updating the values ever so often), but there are tags on the 2nd page that don't change and many on the 3rd page that do. I tested between 30 & 40, and can find no pattern.

Comment: @cigien Thank you. Where did you get the 120 from? Would you mind linking?

Comment: @NateT I vaguely recall using a SEDE query that showed the top tags, and searching till I found the cross-over point. I guess you can use the [popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=3&tab=popular) search, and look for the last tag that doesn't convert.

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work. That is what I was saying in the comment above. between late page 2 of tags and all of page 3, it is hit or miss. That is what has me intrigued. Maybe it is just out of sync?

Comment: Are you searching on MSO, or on SO? I'm only referring to SO, and the few tags I spot checked on page 2 seem to get converted. Can you share an example that doesn't?

Comment: I  was on MSO. Try page 3.  [editor] works, most of the hyphenated ones before it do not (but some do.) Then I went to page 2 and found some there that do not. I can't remember which ones I used exactly, but it is definitely hit / miss in that area. I was looking for a pattern but didn't see anything.

Comment: MSO search may work differently. Please edit the question to clarify where you're searching. Also, your 3rd paragraphs doesn't make sense in the context of MSO tags.

Comment: For the question, I was in SO. I used meta for the tests. Robert Longson said above that search was a single implementation across all sights, but it looks like he deleted most of his comments. I probably need to clean up my mess as well..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146312) to the linked question on Meta Stack Exchange, you can override this behavior by putting the search term in double quotes. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22search%22+%22scope%22